# Datepicker Loading Issue

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am kinda stuck why my datepicker code is not working on my pc, but it does work in a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1Ly092w/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker: Set Date on Page Load</title>
    <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions here?

Comment: If you're running this code on your local file system then you need to use URLs which include the protocol, eg. `http://ajax.googleapis.com/...`. Other than that I can see nothing wrong with your code. Try checking the console for any errors.

Comment: Rory you are right.. Thanks! That's why I told you I was soo stuck in something so trivia..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the source files with

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">/script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```